# CSS Text/Div positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display an html webpage that has an image that covers the entire page. Text that is centered at the top of image, but obviously in front so it can be seen.

Example : https://gyazo.com/8f7015a61a296f71c02e2b4030710074

This is what I'm getting :https://gyazo.com/0a2f9ad37eaf05cd1cb5a623f75d6bca
My text is displaying at the bottom, nor is it over the image.

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:brown;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .title {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            text-align:top;
    }
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Loading Image.." style="width:100%;">
    <div class="title">Oregon Trail:Marist Edition</div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The class name of title dev have typo, `<div class="title">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this. You have given the style for `.title` instead of `.Title`. Please check that. Everything else works as expected.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image" alt="Loading Image.." style="width:100%;">
    <div class="title">Oregon Trail:Marist Edition</div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
    </body>
    </html>
```